# Solving the Helmholtz equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I wanted to figure out how to do a simulation with the Helmholtz equation, how would I do it? Or, what kinds of techniques would I have to learn in order to figure it out?

Background: 1st year Aero Engineering student (this isn't on our syllabus, just general interest)

Thanks!

Comment: Usually the Helmholtz equation arises from solving a PDE. Are you trying to simulate a PDE? If so, you should post it. If it is a finite domain, you can determine the series the solution and truncate that to plot it for different times. On an infinite domain, you will probably go with a Fourier transform numerical method.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the Helmholtz equation rather directly in free space (i.e. the wave speed is constant) is to use a double or single layer potential. So we have
\begin{equation*}
\Delta u + k^{2}u = 0 \quad \textrm{ in } \mathbb{R}^{3}
\end{equation*}

For example, given a smooth boundary $\partial D \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and a function $\phi \in L^{2}(\partial D)$, let
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{D}\phi(x) := \int_{\partial D}\phi(y) \frac{\partial \Phi(x,y)}{\partial \nu_{y}}\, dS_{y}
\end{equation*}
where $\Phi(x,y) = \frac{e^{ik|x-y|}}{4\pi|x-y|}$ is the Green's function in 3D. $\mathcal{D}\phi(x)$ is the double layer potential induced by $\phi$, and is a solution to the Helmholtz equation for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \setminus \partial D$. I recommend the book "Inverse Acoustic and Electromagnetic Scattering Theory" by Colton and Kress.

Another approach, which is more generally applicable, is to use a finite element method, or perhaps even a finite difference scheme. Although, one must then worry a bit more about boundary conditions on the computational domain.